# Adding values allowing a maximum number of NA values using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this:

```
DF = data.frame(month=rep(1:3,3), 
                year=rep(1998:2000,each=3), 
                A=c(NA,3,2,rep(NA,2),4,4,5,NA), 
                B=c(NA,4,5,rep(NA,4),5,6), 
                C=c(10,rep(NA,3),2:4,rep(NA,2)))
> head(DF)
  month  year  A  B  C
1     1  1998 NA NA 10
2     2  1998  3  4 NA
3     3  1998  2  5 NA
4     1  1999 NA NA NA
5     2  1999 NA NA  2
6     3  1999  4 NA  3
```

And I want to get this:

```
   year    A   B   C
1  1998    5   9  NA
2  1999   NA  NA   5
3  2000    9  11  NA
```

The above means that the `sum` function allows 1 `NA` value per `year`.

As a first attempt I tried:

```
library(dplyr)    
DF %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise_all(function(x) sum(x, na.rm=T))
```

But obviously I got the following output as I wrote `na.rm=T`:

```
   year    A   B   C
1  1998    5   9  10
2  1999    4   0   5
3  2000    9  11   4
```

My question is: How could I pass a maximum number of `NA` values to the `sum` function in order to get the intended data frame?

I quite solved it with very complicated `for` and `if` loops but I wonder If I could do it using vectorized functions.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

DF <- data.frame(month=rep(1:3,3), 
           year=rep(1998:2000,each=3), 
           A=c(NA,3,2,rep(NA,2),4,4,5,NA), 
           B=c(NA,4,5,rep(NA,4),5,6), 
           C=c(10,rep(NA,3),2:4,rep(NA,2)))

DF <- DF %>% group_by(year) %>%
  summarise_all(function(x) ifelse(2 * sum(is.na(x)) > length(x), NA, sum(x, na.rm=T)))

DF$month <- NULL
as.data.frame(DF)
#   year  A  B  C
# 1 1998  5  9 NA
# 2 1999 NA NA  5
# 3 2000  9 11 NA
```

Comment: Right logic, but I think you can get away with an `if` and `else` instead of `ifelse` - `summarise_all(function(x) if(sum(is.na(x)) <= 1) sum(x,na.rm=TRUE) else NA  )` since `summarise()` can only return one value anyway.

Comment: Yes, you are right too. In order to admit a different number of allowed NA values I modified Arkadiy's answer: `summarise_all(function(x) ifelse(sum(is.na(x)) > 1, NA, sum(x, na.rm=T)))`. This way it looks like your answer. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

dplyr is doesn't make assigning to a subset easy, but it is possible, so you can assign `0` to the first `NA` value in each group and then use `sum` without `na.rm = TRUE`:

```r
library(dplyr)

DF = data.frame(month = rep(1:3, 3), 
                year = rep(1998:2000, each = 3), 
                A = c(NA, 3, 2, rep(NA, 2), 4, 4, 5, NA), 
                B = c(NA, 4, 5, rep(NA, 4), 5, 6), 
                C = c(10, rep(NA, 3), 2:4, rep(NA, 2)))

DF %>% 
    select(-month) %>% 
    group_by(year) %>% 
    mutate_all(~{.x[which(is.na(.x))[1]] <- 0; .x}) %>%    # or ~ifelse(is.na(.x) & cumsum(is.na(.x)) <= 1, 0, .x)
    summarise_all(sum)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>    year     A     B     C
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  1998     5     9    NA
#> 2  1999    NA    NA     5
#> 3  2000     9    11    NA
```

Comment: Interesting. I'd never seen that kind of code but I guess if I want to allow more `NA` values (let's say 3) I should do this: `mutate_all(~{.x[which(is.na(.x))[c(1:3)]] <- 0; .x})`.

Comment: Yep, thought you don't need the `c`; `1:3` already makes a vector.